# How to get selected index of dynamically generated combobox?

Tags: c#, winforms

How to get the selected index or selected value of a combobox that was created by a function? I created a form and added comboboxes and textboxes. The value of a combobox affects the value of the next one and so on:

```
Form Edit = new Form();
ComboBox contract = new ComboBox();
ComboBox finyear = new ComboBox();
Button Update = new Button();
Button Cancel = new Button();
Label fyLbl = new Label();
Label ContractLbl = new Label();

SQLiteConnection _connection = new SQLiteConnection();
_connection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=mydb.db;Version=3");
_connection.Open();

string qr = "SELECT ContractId,Name FROM Contract";
using (SQLiteDataAdapter sda = new SQLiteDataAdapter(qr, _connection))
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);

        DataRow dataRow = dt.NewRow();
        dataRow[0] = 0;
        dataRow[1] = "Select...";
        dt.Rows.InsertAt(dataRow, 0);

        contract.DataSource = dt;
        contract.DisplayMember = "Name";
        contract.ValueMember = "ContractId";
    }

int contractId = contract.SelectedIndex;
```

The last line is always null. Comboboxes created with the Designer can work with `SelectedIndexChanged` but since my controls are not accessible outside this function, what can I do?

Comment: `contract.SelectionChangeCommitted += (_, __) => { long value = (long)contract.SelectedValue; };`, assuming the Type of `ContractId` is `long`, cast to what it is -- Not clear what kind of cascading effect you want to achieve (how this selection affects other Controls) -- It's probably simpler if you use a pre-built Form model that can handle parameters

Comment: @Jimi Yes contractId is long. So I need the contractId to populate the financial years linked to that selected contract.

Comment: Well, then in the same handler, setup the query that selects and filters the records you need, setting the `WHERE` clause with the `value` just selected. Do the same for each ComboBox  -- If you pre-build a Form for this Task, you can use methods that accept the selected values and use them as filters, with the aid of BindingSource objects that connect the different ComboBox Controls. Doing this all on-the-fly may get messy

Comment: It's already messy. This whole function is coming from an Edit click even on a datagridview table.

Comment: You can always open the designer.cs file to get example of event.  You can copy the code from the designer to your cs modules.